# ERROR WHILE USING STRING AS A RETURN TYPE IN GETTER IN DART

Tags: flutter, dart, getter

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XELG1.png)

```
String get resultPhrase 
{
   var resultText= 'you'; 
     if(resultScore<=8){
            resultText ='you are innocent!';
          }
     else{
            resultText = 'you are ambigous!';
          }
   return resultText;
}
```

ERROR : {

```
"code": "missing_function_body",
"message": "A function body must be provided.\nTry adding a function body.",
"source": "dart",
```

[return type string is giving an error while declaring this getter as it's not recognising it's body.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XELG1.png)

Comment: I think you might have forgotten the `;` after the constructor above.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your constructor. It needs to finish with `;`.

Look at the example bellow:

```
class Result {
  final String txt;

  Result(this.txt)

  String get text  {
    return "Ok";
  }
}
```

The method `get text` is ok... But the compiler will throw you an error like: `A function body must be provided`.

If you change to `Result(this.txt);`, the error goes away..

Also, it's very important to provide the complete file with error... I just found this looking at the picture you attached...